# Standardized coefficients to zero mean

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, excel

I was reading in the literature that in order to compare linear regression results with independent variables & categorical (variables), it is recommended to standardize the coefficients to a zero mean.

I am trying to do linear regression where Y in my model comprises birth rate, X1 the monthly temperature, and 11 dummy variables representing Jan-Nov. While running it in Microsoft Excel, I am not sure whether the coefficient values are standardized or not. Is there a way to check it and is it possible to normalize coeff. to a zero mean in Excel?

Comment: Although this question is asking for Excel solutions, there are underlying statistical issues that need to be addressed (& which, when addressed, will take care of the problem). This should be considered on topic here, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to standardize the coefficients- you have to standardize the regressors. In that sense, you have to take your regressors, de-mean them (subtract the mean), and then divide by the standard deviation. Now, you coefficient $\beta$ measures the marginal effect of $x$ on $y$ in standard deviation units, is therefore unitless, and can be compared across regressors.